# I can't token my char how can I get there?

Tags: c++, c, file, io, token

```
using namespace std;

char *fx[65537];

void main()
{

    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    char *token = NULL;
    char str1[] = " ";

    fp = fopen("fx.txt", "r");
    char s[51];
    for (c = 0; i <= 65536; c++) 
    {
        token = strtok(fx[c], str1);
        while (token != NULL) 
        {
            printf("token : %s", token);
            putchar('\n');
            token = strtok(NULL, str1);
        }
    }

    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        i = i++;
        fgets(s, 50, fp);
        fx[i] = s;  //fx 포인터에 s의 임시배열 저장
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Hello
I want make a program that read the *.txt file with one line and save char pointer
and I token this char and save
For example

there txt
test.txt

```
123 654 8765 4213
321 565 4687 8765
652 126 6874 3215
```

then,

```
char *a[3] = {123 654 8765 4213, 321 565 4687 8765, 652 126 6874 3215};
char b[3][4];
char b[0][] = {123, 654, 8765, 4213};
char b[1][] = {321, 565, 4687, 8765};
char b[2][] = {652, 126, 6874, 3215};
```

But I don't know how to that :(

Can you help me?

Comment: What's your `fx[c]` ? Are you reading it from your file before `strtok`-ing it?

Comment: `i = i++;` is undefined behaviour

Comment: Now I'm edit my code.

Comment: Generally, one would use `std::string` and `iostream` for this in C++.

Comment: `main` must return `int`.

Comment: you never allocated memory for `fx`

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  There are different solutions available in C++ that are not available in C.

Comment: Strange.  You parse for tokens in an uninitialized array, then you read data from the file.  Isn't this backwards?  You should read text from the file first then parse the text you have.

Answer (score 1):

use vector and string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::ifstream input("fx.txt");
  std::vector<std::string> v((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(input)),std::istream_iterator<std::string>());

  for ( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = v.begin();iter != v.end(); ++iter ) {
    std::cout << *iter << std::endl;//print by iterator
  }
  for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i)
    std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;//print by []
}
```

---

By C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *fx[65537];

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0, j;
    int c = 0;
    char *token = NULL;
    char str1[] = " \n";
    char s[51];

    fp = fopen("fx.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp)){
        token = strtok(s, str1);
        while (token != NULL) {
            fx[i++] = strdup(token);
            if(i == 65537)
                break;
            token = strtok(NULL, str1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    c = i;
    for(i=0;i<c;++i)
        printf("%s ", fx[i]);
    printf("\n\n");

    char *(*b)[4] = (char *(*)[4])fx;
    for(i=0;i<3;++i){
        for(j=0;j<4;++j)
            printf("%s ", b[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    //deallocation
    for(i=0;i<c;++i)
        free(fx[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Umm...I think it's diffrent my thought.. It doesnt devide char *a[3] = {123 654 8765 4213, 321 565 4687 8765, 652 126 6874 3215};...

Comment: @user3844979 I have added a sample in C.

Comment: It has error. fgets has an error! :( My programming level is so low....:( I don't know how to fix it..

Comment: @user3844979 What do you an _error_? if example's file name was different. (Edited. `"data.txt"` --> `"fx.txt"`)

Comment: Debug Assertion Failed!

Program : ...cuments\visual studio
2013\Projects\fxToNum\fxToNum.exe
File : f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdio\fgets.c
Line:57

Expression : (str!=NULL)

Comment: @user3844979 It's not a error not because of my code. also fgets returns NULL last When you have read through the last of file.

Comment: I can't understand what you saying.. And I don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: @user3844979 `fgets()` return `s` on success, and NULL on error or when `end of file occurs` while no characters have been read.

Comment: @user3844979 There is no need for `assert`.

Comment: I want send you a message... heracy@outlook.com is my email.. If you can help me, please send me a email! :)

Comment: You send me a message, I'll send my txt file

Answer (score 0):

If there are no restrictions, use strings, get boost and then you can use

```
vector<string>splitString;
boost::split(splitString,a[i],boost::is_any_of(" "));
```

this way each element in your string vector (splitString) will contain one "number" of the ith line.